# Can a Service be killed by the Android system while its onStartCommand is executing?

Tags: android

The different flags which `onStartCommand` returns specify how the service should be restarted after `onStartCommand` returns, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY) for the `START_NOT_STICKY` flags says:

> Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), and there are no new start intents to deliver to it, then take the service out of the started state and don't recreate until a future explicit call to Context.startService(Intent). The service will not receive a onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) call with a null Intent because it will not be re-started if there are no pending Intents to deliver.
>
> This mode makes sense for things that want to do some work as a result of being started, but can be stopped when under memory pressure and will explicit start themselves again later to do more work. An example of such a service would be one that polls for data from a server: it could schedule an alarm to poll every N minutes by having the alarm start its service. When its onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) is called from the alarm, it schedules a new alarm for N minutes later, and spawns a thread to do its networking. If its process is killed while doing that check, the service will not be restarted until the alarm goes off.

If a `Service` can't be killed while its `onStartCommand` is executing and the `Service` finishes the work it needs to do in `onStartCommand`, I don't understand the need for the different flags.

Comment: "...Service finishes the work it needs to do in onStartCommand..." - What if the `Service` needs to do work after `onStartCommand()` has finished?

Comment: @MikeM. in background threads?